# Change buttonStyle Modifier based on light or dark mode in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, button, swiftui, ios-darkmode

I want to set Custom `buttonStyle` modifier for button for light and dark mode. 
How to change buttonStyle Modifier based on light or dark mode? I want to set Custom modifier for my button for light and dark mode.

here is my button code,

```
Button(action: {
    print("button tapped")

}, label: {
    LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.darkBlueColor, .lightBlueColor]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
        .mask(Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    ).frame(width: iPhoneSE ? 26 : 25, height: iPhoneSE ? 26 : 25, alignment: .center)
})
.buttonStyle(lightButtonStyle())

struct lightButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
        .padding(10)
        .background(
            Group {
                if configuration.isPressed {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.offWhite)
                        .overlay(

                            Circle()
                                .stroke(Color.lightGray2, lineWidth: 4)
                                .blur(radius: 1)
                                .offset(x: 2, y: 2)
                                .mask(Circle().fill(LinearGradient(Color.black, Color.clear)))
                        )
                        .overlay(
                            Circle()
                                .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4)
                                .blur(radius: 1)
                                .offset(x: -2, y: -2)
                                .mask(Circle().fill(LinearGradient(Color.clear, Color.black)))
                        )
                } else {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.offWhite)
                        .shadow(color: Color.white.opacity(0.8), radius: 1, x: -2, y: -2)
                        .shadow(color: Color.lightPurple.opacity(0.6), radius: 1, x: 2, y: 2)
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

For Dark mode i've another buttonStyle with different color and shadows.

i know we can change other modifiers like this,

```
.fill(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.darkEnd : Color.white)
```

But some how i'm not able to change `buttonStyle` modifier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just put that condition *inside* button style modifier, like

```
// ... other your code
})
.buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle(scheme: colorScheme)) // << here !!
```

and in custom style

```
struct CustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    var scheme: ColorScheme              // << here !!

    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
        .padding(10)
            Group {
                if configuration.isPressed {
                    Circle()   // example of internal dependency on scheme
                        .fill(self.scheme == .dark ? Color.offBlack :  Color.offWhite)

    // .. other code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a named color in Assets.xcassets with a variation for the dark mode:

[image]

This works out of the box even in a ButtonStyle:

```swift
Color("ButtonBorder")
```