# How to change between button styles if a condition is true in SwiftUI?

Tags: button, swiftui

I have 2 custom button styles and I want to change the style when I tap the button. I tried this way:

```
Button(action: {
    self.pressed.toggle()
})
{
    Text("Button")
}.buttonStyle(pressed ? style1() : style2())
```

But it is not working, it is giving me an error from the VStack that it belongs to:

```
Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate
```

If I do something like:

```
.buttonStyle(style1())
```

Or

```
.buttonStyle(style2())
```

Then the error goes away, so it's not from style1() or style2().

Answer (score 4):

It's swift type-checking violation... I would recommend instead

```
Button(action: {
    self.pressed.toggle()
})
{
    Text("Button")
}.buttonStyle(Your_style(condition: pressed)) // << put conditional styling inside
```

See for example solution in [Change buttonStyle Modifier based on light or dark mode in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61947741/12299030)

Answer (score 3):

You can write an extension on `View` to apply different modifiers conditionally based on a boolean condition. This can be useful when you want to customize the appearance or behavior of a view based on some state.

First, make sure you have the following extension defined:

```swift
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func `if`<TrueContent: View, FalseContent: View>(
        _ condition: Bool,
        if ifTransform: (Self) -> TrueContent,
        else elseTransform: (Self) -> FalseContent
    ) -> some View {
        if condition {
            ifTransform(self)
        } else {
            elseTransform(self)
        }
    }
}
```

With this extension, you can apply condition-based modifiers to views. Let's take the example of a `Button` from the question:

```swift
Button {
    print("")
} label: {
    Text("Hello World!")
}
.if(vm.status == .subscribed, if: { button in
    button.buttonStyle(TertiaryButton())
}, else: { button in
    button.buttonStyle(SecondaryButton())
})
```

Comment: Fantastic answer!! I was looking to conditionally apply a button style to a button and the other answers don't work for that. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a useful extension like below

```swift
extension View {

    func conditionalModifier<M1: ViewModifier, M2: ViewModifier>
        (on condition: Bool, trueCase: M1, falseCase: M2) -> some View {
        Group {
            if condition {
                self.modifier(trueCase)
            } else {
                self.modifier(falseCase)
            }
        }
    }

    func conditionalModifier<M: ViewModifier>
        (on condition: Bool, trueCase: M) -> some View {
        Group {
            if condition {
                self.modifier(trueCase)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Usage;

```swift
@State var condition = false
var body: some View {
    Text("conditional modifier")
       // Apply style if condition is true, otherwise do nothing
       .conditionalModifier(on: condition, trueCase: Style1())

       // Decision between 2 style
       .conditionalModifier(on: condition, trueCase: Style1(), falseCase: Style2())
}
```

Comment: This approach causes SwiftUI to lose track of the view's identity, which can break animation. [More info](https://www.objc.io/blog/2021/08/24/conditional-view-modifiers/)