# Enable/disable a button on conditions such as textfield text are nonempty in swiftui? This is not based on Pressed Button State

Tags: ios, button, swiftui, configuration, styles

I am new to swiftui and learning it.

I have a situation where I have to Pass different ButtonStyle to Button based on the conditions. I have created 2 different button styles based on the requirement but was unable to provide the button.

These are 2 button styles created.

```
struct PrimaryButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
        
        func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
            configuration.label
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .font(.system(size: CGFloat(15)))
                .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.95: 1)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .animation(.spring())
                .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.primaryColor, .accentBlue]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
        }
    }
    
    struct DeactivatedButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
        func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
            configuration.label
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .font(.system(size: CGFloat(15)))
                .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.95: 1)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .animation(.spring())
                .background(Color.lightGrayGradient)
        }
    }
```

This is the body of a view.

```
var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        Text("Data")
        Spacer()
        
        Button("SAVE", action: {
            callButtonAction()
        })
            .buttonStyle(canSave() ? PrimaryButtonStyle() : DeactivatedButtonStyle())
            .frame(maxHeight: 45)
    }
}
```

This is a function gets called canSave(), which check certain mandatory field are nonempty.

```
func canSave() -> Bool {
    return firstName.isEmpty || lastName.isEmpty
}
```

Based on the canSave function, I have to change the style. but I am getting the below error.

Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'PrimaryButtonStyle' and 'DeactivatedButtonStyle'

Please do not mark it duplicate and do not close it.

My Problem is not resolved with this link.

[How to change between button styles if a condition is true in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62008967/how-to-change-between-button-styles-if-a-condition-is-true-in-swiftui)

The above link provides the button action which is based on isPressed. My Problem statement is entirely different from this.

Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: The referenced topic idea is not about `isPressed`, but about `buttonStyle`, which cannot accept two different types, so you have to pass condition into *one* style and handle it internally.

Answer (score 1):

The nature of the Boolean (whether it’s `isPressed` or `canSave()`) doesn’t matter here. The difference in your styles is only in the gradient. So the solution is to pass the flag into the style as a parameter or to read `isEnabled` from the environment:

```
struct PrimaryButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

    @Environment(\.isEnabled) private var isEnabled

    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .font(.system(size: CGFloat(15)))
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.95: 1)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .animation(.spring())
            .background(gradientBackground)
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var gradientBackground: some View {
         if isEnabled { 
             LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.primaryColor, .accentBlue]), 
                            startPoint: .topLeading, 
                            endPoint: .bottomTrailing) 
         } else {
             Color.lightGrayGradient
         }
    }
}
```

Then, you can change the state with `.disabled(!canSave())`:

```
var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        Text("Data")
        Spacer()
        
        Button("SAVE") {
            callButtonAction()
        }
            .buttonStyle(PrimaryButtonStyle())
            .disabled(!canSave())
            .frame(maxHeight: 45)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'LinearGradient' and 'Color'. on the below Statement.               .background(isEnabled ? LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.primaryColor, .accentBlue]), 
                                                   startPoint: .topLeading, 
                                                   endPoint: .bottomTrailing) 
                                  : Color.lightGrayGradient)

Comment: My assumption was that `Color.lightGrayGradient` has the same type as `LinearGradient` has, because you haven't provided the code where you show what type of `Color.lightGrayGradient` is.

Comment: @user1960279 check the updated answer - I wrapped the background as a view builder.